# How to set the target vector for training images in neural network?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network

I am training a neural network to recognize three different signs (stop sign, no-left sign and no-entry sign). I have taken 50 images for each class. Every picture has size of 8x8 matrix, so my input then will be 150x64 matrix and output  - 3x1 matrix, but how do I assign the target for these images, also do I have to normalize these images before proceeding to the training part?

Comment: This problem is very similar to the handwritten digit recognition problem (MNIST) where the input is also an image and the output 10 different categories. There are tons of documentation and papers about the MNIST problem, so I'd reccomend running it, understanding what they are doing and adapting it to your problem.   [http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)

Comment: Why is your input of shape 150x64?

Comment: because i have taken 50 images each of three different signs and all of them are  resized to 8x8 pixel.

Comment: So - they are in greyscale? Not coloured?

Comment: Your output should be a 150x3 matrix: 150 examples with 3 possible classes.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko yes they are in grayscale.

Comment: @hbaderts clear with the output part but what about the target?

Comment: You should use a one hot encoding of your classes.

Comment: The target is always the same size as the output. The target is exactly what you want the output to be. Thus for a perfectly trained network, the output = the target. As mentioned in the answer, you have to create the target yourself, and define what you want.

Comment: If I need to train only the first image and take another two signs as negative then the target will be 150x1?

Comment: If you train only with one image, your target will be one number a vector with 3 values, the score of each class. The target must be a NxC, where N is the number of input images (class independent, so 150 in your case) and C is the number of classes (3) as @hbaderts wrote. If you want to use the instances of other classes as negative samples, the target will change, becoming a one vs all problem of shape Nx2 (N=input, 2=|yes,no|). In this case you must train a binary classifier for each possible class and at test time use the most confident prediction between all of them.

Comment: @LemmRas in your second example, shouldn't it be N=1? You don't need separate outputs for "yes" and "no".

Comment: So of the three classes takin two as negative samples , the output will be of the form [1 1 1....0 0.... upto 150] ie 1 for the positive samples and 0 for the negative?

Comment: @hbaderts Absolutely, I made a mistake

Comment: Got it thanx for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images do not have labels (the targets), you have to labels them yourself, of course. Labeling 50 images should not take much time.

Also you have to normalize the images in some way, either min-max or subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation, neural network training will fail if you don't.

Comment: Will fail? Not could fail?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko It is very likely to fail. It should be stressed that normalization is a positive thing to do.